# Install apache2 on Linux cannot verify root:root

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, permissions, installation

I'm trying to run apache2 on my Ubuntu (Opensuse 42.1).
The result of my installing doesn't look that good. 
Do anybody know how to get the apache work?
[image: Result of installing....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug reported in

https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-bugs/2013-11/msg02991.html

for opensuse and apache2.4 that you are trying to install. If you are not forced to use apache2.4, the simplest way is to use apache2.2 that works well on opensuse.